# Azure active directory assign roles to users within groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am making an application where users can join multiple azure groups. This works fine. But a user should be able to have a role only within that specific group. So a user can have different roles in different groups.

Does anyone know how I can assign roles that only exist within a group?
and then get the role for a user within a specific group via the graph api?

Answer (score 0):

To Assign the role to a user please "[Add directory role member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)"to assign a particular role in a group.

For different types of roles that you can assign to a user please refer "[Azure AD built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#all-roles)"

Hope this helps.